# How can I read an encrypted password from the database to allow users access?

Tags: php, mysqli, blowfish

I am unable to match the password returned by the crypt() function to allow users access.

My cryptPassword function:

```
function cryptPass($input, $rounds = 9) {
    $salt = '';
    $saltChars = array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z'), range(0, 9));
    for ($i = 0; $i < 22; $i++) {
        $salt .= $saltChars[array_rand($saltChars)];
    }
    return crypt($input, sprintf('$2y$%02d$', $rounds) . $salt);
}
```

My registration form:

```
if($_POST['register']) { 
    if($_POST['username'] && $_POST['email'] && $_POST['password']) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['username']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, cryptPass($_POST['password']));
         // insert into databse...
    }
}
```

My login form:

```
if($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password']) {  
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['username']);
    $inputPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $_POST['password']);
    $password = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = '$inputPassword'";
    $hashedPass = cryptPass($password);
    if(crypt($inputPassword, $hashedPass) == $hashedPass) {
        die("<br>Password is a match. Log in");
    } else {
        echo "<br>Passwords do not match!!! Do NOT log user in <br>";
    }
}
```

I have tested to see why I am unable to log the users in, these are the results:

- user name: 2, password: 2 - logging in -> results ->

**Passwords do not match!!! Do NOT log user in:**

```
$inputPassword = 2
$query password = SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = '2'
$hashedPass = $2y$09$ICAfpjSJyXEp93JsUbhyieaeMX7KNC6vQSayc0nT6QLHWrMjdYQhi
crypt($inputPassword, $hashedPass) = $2y$09$ICAfpjSJyXEp93JsUbhyie9dqXeWEVqCYGR3faLHveUp1LsJegxpu
```

As you can see, the first part is identical ($2y$09$ICAfpjSJyXEp93JsUbhyie), however the other part is constantly changing. I believe it has to do with the $salt I'm adding? If so, how can I match the passwords to allow access to my users?

Comment: you never run your query. so you're crypting your SQL statement, which is just bizarre... and why would you crypt a query result anyways (if you were running the query?) That implies you're storing passwords in plaintext in the DB, which begs the question of why you hash both in the first place? `crypt($pw_from_db) == crypt($pw_from_user)` is pointless if you have the plain text, and could just do `$pw_from_db == $pw_from_user`

Comment: I am not storing the passwords in plain text in the database. I just skipped the insert query part  of the code from the registration form as I believed it was not relevant. 

When I'm adding the user to my database I'm storing the password resulted from this variable: 

$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, cryptPass($_POST['password']));

Comment: i also, am curious as to why you're crypting the passwords. most people would instead, hash the password using password_hash(), store that value in the db and then, when the user logs in, hash the submitted password and compare that to the password hash stored in the db. am i missing the reason for you using crypt()?

Comment: No real reason behind using crypt(), I'm new to all this and just trying to learn. It doesn't have to be crypt(); I'm just looking for something that would work - store passwords on database (not plain text) and be able to read them when the user is trying to log in. The way I'm doing it now, the user won't be allowed access even if the password entered is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [hash_equals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php). Also, [here](https://alias.io/2010/01/store-passwords-safely-with-php-and-mysql/) is an article on the implementation.